# How to enter login/password details and get data

Tags: c#, authentication, web, http-get

There is a one website and I want to get data to my C# application from there.

I enter url on web browser like this `http://x.com/api/MY_ID`, firstly I get this messagebox for the login.

[image: screenshot]

And when I enter my account I get this response.

```
{"success":true,"message":null}
```

I want to do this on C#, to return this response on variable. I tried some methods with `HttpWebRequest`, `WebClient` but I couldn't do it (I had some errors with 405 Method not allowed) Can anyone help me on this? T

Comment: Can you show some of the source code of your attempts? It would be great to have some starting point.

Comment: I solved my question, i will post it on answer later. Thank you very much for the comment

Comment: It looks like the question is too specific for your situation and can be safely removed.

Answer (score 2):

thanks for the comment, i dont know how but i found my solution quickly when i posted here, really sorry. With this example code i solved it.

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        String username = "ID";
        String password = "PW";
        string url = "http://x.com/api/" + username;

        client.Credentials =  new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username,password);

        string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));

        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + credentials;

        var result = client.DownloadString(url);
        textBox1.Text = result;
```